How to decode Iron Fish raw transaction
I need to get the hash of a transaction from rawTx. It will be great if you show how to implement this on Golang.
func main() {
    rawTxHex := "rawTx"

    rawTxBytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(rawTxHex)

    // Получение хэша транзакции
    txHash := getHash(rawTxBytes)

    fmt.Println("Tx Hash:", hex.EncodeToString(txHash))
}

func getHash(raw []byte) []byte {
    hash := sha256.Sum256(raw)
    hash = sha256.Sum256(hash[:])
    return hash[:]
}


Please explain more. What transaction ? What is your problem with your attached source code ? What is you expectation ?

rawTxBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(rawTx)
 if err != nil {
     return models.Transaction{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to decode raw transaction: %w", err)
 }

 hashByte := blake3.Sum256(rawTxBytes)

 hash := hex.EncodeToString(hashByte[:])


So you solved your problem, and no longer need help from the community?

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
